# Checking a DataFrame string value contains words with certain prefixes

Tags: python, string, pandas

First time working with Pandas, and I'm struggling to query the DataFrame for this spec.

Let's say I create a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(_file, names=['UID', 'Comment', 'Author', 'Relevancy'])
```

Which gives:

```
UID  .     Comment           .  Author .  Relevancy
1234 . motorcycles are cool  . dave    . 12
5678 . motorhomes are cooler . mike    . 13
9101 . i love motorbikes     . frank   . 14
```

I need to return all of these rows when I query the word 'motor'.

I.e. a row should be returned if it's "Comment" string contains a word that is prefixed by a given word.

I essentially want to do something like:

```
df["Comment"][any(word in df["Comment"].str.split() if word.startswith("motor"))]
```

Any help and direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas `str` operations aren't vectorised. You can use a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Comment': ['motorcycles are cool', 'motorhomes are cooler',
                               'i love motorbikes', 'nomotor test string',
                               'some other test string']})

flag = [any(w.startswith('motor') for w in x.casefold().split()) for x in df['Comment']]
res = df.loc[flag]

print(res)

                 Comment
0   motorcycles are cool
1  motorhomes are cooler
2      i love motorbikes
```

A less efficient version is possible which uses Pandas `str` methods:

```
def check_words(x):
    return any(w.startswith('motor') for w in x)

flag = df['Comment'].str.lower().str.split().map(check_words)
res = df.loc[flag]
```

Comment: Oh my lord you beautiful human, this did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: If i wanted to also search the Author column for motor in the same way, how do I implement that? I tried adding it to the list comprehension operator like ... in df[['Comment', 'Author']] but it didn't like that.

Comment: Something like `flag = [any(w.startswith('motor') for i in (x, y) for w in i.casefold().split()) for x, y in zip(df['Comment'], df['Author'])]`